# Site Login via Access Codes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization, form-authentication

I need to semi-secure(meaning people could give these access codes away, and it will work for anyone) a site using access codes, no username or passwords, just a 5 digit access codes. But I would want to be able to still use the [Authorize] functionality.  I believe I will I can't use the default membership (as its not really a membership), any ideas on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use the standard SQL Membership providers.
2. Use your 5-digit access code as the username
3. Hardcode a default password in your controllers (so the user interface never sees it).

Caution should be used because this is **very unsecure**.

Comment: That's a good idea.  Yes it is very unsecure, but it's not secure info, they just want to make you feel special for having an access code.